# A-Z grid view/search view for filtering in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am looking for a Silverlight component which can show me a A-Z grid view. Refer to image below:
[image: Windows Phone Search View]
Can someone tell me the name of this component or library where I can get this view. (It is tightly integrated with a long list, to filter the results.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a  LongListSelector control in the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888) that can be used for generating such lists.

Comment: As an addition, those lists are called "Jump Lists". They cannot only be with chars from A to Z, but also with category names, dates, numbers, ...